# How to get the data stored in a SharedPreference from a Fragment in another (Kotlin)

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

I've tried many other solutions but none have worked for me, I do not know what's wrong with my code. I'm a beginner and any answer is welcome, thanks.
First fragment:

```
class settingsFragment : Fragment() {

override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
                          savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
    val binding: FragmentSettingsBinding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(
            inflater, R.layout.fragment_settings, container, false)

    fun onSave() {
        val pref:SharedPreferences? = activity?.getSharedPreferences("SHARED_PREF", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
        val editor: SharedPreferences.Editor? = pref?.edit()
        editor?.putString("STATE_ONE", "true")
        editor?.apply()
        Toast.makeText(context,"Settings Saved",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    }

    binding.applyButton.setOnClickListener {
        onSave()
        view?.findNavController()?.navigate(R.id.action_settingsFragment_to_startFragment)
    }
    return binding.root
  }
}
```

Second fragment:

```
    class startFragment : Fragment() {

override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
                          savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View {
    val binding: FragmentStartBinding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(
            inflater, R.layout.fragment_start, container, false)

    binding.btnStart.setOnClickListener { view: View ->
        val preferences:SharedPreferences? = activity?.getSharedPreferences("SHARED_PREF", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
        val state1 = preferences?.getString("STATE_ONE", "")
        Toast.makeText(context, state1, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    }
    binding.btnSettings.setOnClickListener { view: View ->
        view.findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_startFragment_to_settingsFragment)
    }
    return binding.root
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use sharedPreferences like this instead of call editor from SharedPreferences

```
class SettingFragment : Fragment() {
    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {
        val binding by lazy { FragmentSettingBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false) }

        fun onSave() {
            val pref = requireActivity().getSharedPreferences("SHARED_PREF", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
            pref?.edit { putString("STATE_ONE", "true") }

            Toast.makeText(context, "Settings Saved", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()

            findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_settingFragment_to_startFragment)
        }

        binding.btnApply.setOnClickListener { onSave() }

        return binding.root
    }
}
```

```
class StartFragment : Fragment() {

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {
        val binding by lazy { FragmentStartBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false) }

        binding.btnStart.setOnClickListener {
            val pref = requireActivity().getSharedPreferences("SHARED_PREF", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
            val state = pref?.getString("STATE_ONE", "")

            Toast.makeText(context, state, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }

        return binding.root
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, really helped me a lot :)

Comment: Urwelll, happy learning and keep your spirit :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to edit your code like this:

```
    class settingsFragment : Fragment() {

        override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
                              savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
            val binding: FragmentSettingsBinding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(
                    inflater, 
                    R.layout.fragment_settings, 
                    container, 
                    false
                )

            binding.applyButton.setOnClickListener {
                onSave()

                view?.findNavController()?.navigate(R.id.action_settingsFragment_to_startFragment)
            }

            return binding.root
        }

        fun onSave() {
            requireActivity().getSharedPreferences("SHARED_PREF", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
                .edit()
                .putString("STATE_ONE", "true")
                .apply()
                
            Toast.makeText(context,"Settings Saved",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }
    }
```

```
    class startFragment : Fragment() {

        override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
                                savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View {
            val binding: FragmentStartBinding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(
                    inflater, 
                    R.layout.fragment_start, 
                    container, 
                    false
                )

            binding.btnStart.setOnClickListener { view: View ->
                val state1 = getState()
                
                Toast.makeText(context, state1, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            }

            binding.btnSettings.setOnClickListener { view: View ->
                view.findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_startFragment_to_settingsFragment)
            }
            return binding.root
        }

        private fun getState() : String {
            return requireActivity()
                        .getSharedPreferences("SHARED_PREF", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
                        .getString("STATE_ONE", "")
        }
    }
```